# Got Error in cast function while converting 60 digit number to bigint

Tags: sql-server-2017

Arithmetic overflow error occurred converting expression to data type bigint when I am applying cast function on a 60 digit number.

Comment: [Bigint][1] is a 64-bit signed integer. The largest possible value is therefore 9,223,372,036,854,775,807: `SELECT CAST(0x7fffffffffffffff AS bigint);`. Are you planning to perform arithmetic on the value?

Comment: can add your code with error coming.

Answer (score 0):

The largest positive value which [`BIGINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can store is `2^63-1`, which is roughly `1x10^18`.  Using [`DECIMAL` or `NUMERIC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) would get you larger storage, up to `1x10^38`.  But neither can accommodate 60 digits of precision.

You might want to ask yourself whether you really need to maintain so much precision for a large number as this.